# In my autocomplete search bar in django app i want that user always gets the most relevant search when he type his query in search bar

Tags: django, autocomplete

So suppose in my app there is a product name "DispoVan 10ml 21mg" and when user gives its query in search bar as 'DispoVan' it works fine but as he mis spell or do some typo error in search query like "dispo 1" search bar did not suggest him any product. i want that if user searches for any product and even if he do some typing error in the name of the product he should get the relevant product. even is there is a space in the search query,any relevant matches should be shown to him.

This is my view which is showing list of all the products which matches to search.

```py
def search_address(request):
    address = request.GET.get('query')
    payload = []
    print(address)
    if address:
        prod = Product.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=address)
        ).values_list('name',flat=True)
        for prod in prod:
            payload.append(prod)
    return JsonResponse({'status':200, 'data':payload})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible approaches to this, so I won't provide a full solution, but some suggestions.

If you are using the PostgreSQL database backend, and install the pg_trgm extension, you can use Trigram similarity to approximate fuzzy search: [Full text search # Trigram similarity | Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigram-similarity).

Alternatively you could use a third party search engine service such as Algolia, Solr, or Elasticsearch, and investigate its features.

Assuming the Postgres option, your code could look like:

```py
    if address:
        prod = Product.objects.annotate(
            similarity=TrigramSimilarity("name", address),
        ).filter(
           similarity__gt=0.3
        ).order_by("-similarity")
        payload = prod  # since prod is an iterable, you don't need to loop over it
```

Note also that for autocomplete searches in general, even without fuzzy matching, you may prefer to use full text search rather than Django's `__icontains` filter, because the latter insists that the entire string is a substring of the field in question. See SearchQuery and SearchRank at [Full text search | Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/)

Comment: thanks nimasami for ypur suggestion but i am using sqlite.i have added updated code which works for me in answer section

Answer (score 0):

can you check this code by replacing your code and please **test** it,

```
payload = []
address = request.GET.get('query')
splited_text = address.split(' ', 1)
if address:
    related_data = Product.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=address) |
           reduce(operator.or_,
           (
               Q(name__icontains=result)
               for result in splited_text
           )
           )
    ).values_list('name', flat=True)

    if related_data.exists():
        try:
            payload = get_close_matches(address, related_data, n=3,cutoff=0.6)
        except Exception as _:
            payload = related_data.first()
    return JsonResponse({'status':200, 'data':payload})
```

Comment: Thank u brother your code was partially true i made some changes and then it worked for me. i have attached my updated code in answer section

Answer (score 0):

```
    payload = []
    address = request.GET.get('query')
    splited_text = address.split(' ', 1)
    if address:
        related_data = 
        Product.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=address) |
           reduce(operator.or_,
           (
               Q(name__icontains=result)
               for result in splited_text
           )
           )
    )
        new_related_data=related_data.order_by(
            Case(
                *[
                    When(name__startswith=item, then=i)
                    for i, item in enumerate(splited_text)
                 ],
                  default=len(splited_text),
                  output_field=models.IntegerField(),
    )
)
```